# Styling html file input button and "no file selected" text

Tags: html, css

I am building a html form that needs file uplod. While I got the file upload part working, I am unable to get the styling of form upload button and " No file selected" text.

My desired markup is 
[image]

Is there a way to do it?

PS: Please ignore the green text ( "Upload a screen shot"). I have that working.

Current behavior the button and the "no file chosen"is in the same line.

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="formField">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Upload a screen shot (optional) </label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/> 
 </div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5tLokkjh/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML file upload "no file selected" text style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608288/html-file-upload-no-file-selected-text-style)

Answer (score 0):

You could enter a line break after the label:

```html
<div class="formField">
  <label for="fileToUpload">Upload a screen shot (optional)</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/> 
</div>
```

But it's much better to use CSS:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="formField">
  <label for="fileToUpload">Upload a screen shot (optional)</label>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
</div>
```

Setting `display: block` on an element makes it fill the entire width of the page.

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't behave the way I need it ( like in the image in my first post).